# Why my code is not fetching updated details from API's even after changing state in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render

I am using two components: LandingPage and SearchMovie. SearchMovie component is updating searchTerm (onChange) and passing it to LandingPage(Parent component) which is fetching movies from API. I checked in console.log and SearchTerm state is updating but LandingPage is not re rendering with updated state of searchTerm. How can I do it? I am posting the code here:

**

> LandingPage code:

**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react'
import { Typography, Row } from 'antd';
import { API_URL, API_KEY, IMAGE_BASE_URL, IMAGE_SIZE, POSTER_SIZE } from '../../Config'
import MainImage from './Sections/MainImage'
import GridCard from '../../commons/GridCards'
import SearchMenu from '../LandingPage/Sections/SearchMenu'
const { Title } = Typography;


function LandingPage(props) {

    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');
    console.log("searchIitialTerm = " + searchTerm);

    const buttonRef = useRef(null);

    const [Movies, setMovies] = useState([])
    const [MainMovieImage, setMainMovieImage] = useState(null)
    const [Loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
    const [CurrentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(0)

    console.log(props.SearchMenu);
    console.log("searchTermLanding = " + searchTerm);
    var path;
    var loadpath;
    
    onchange = (searchTerm) => {
        if (searchTerm != '') {

            path = `${API_URL}search/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&query=${searchTerm}&page=1`;  
        
            loadpath = `${API_URL}search/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&query=${searchTerm}&page=${CurrentPage + 1}`;            
            
        }
        else if (searchTerm == '') {
            
            path = `${API_URL}movie/popular?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&page=1`;
            
            loadpath = `${API_URL}movie/popular?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&page=${CurrentPage + 1}`;
                
            
        }

    }
    

    useEffect(() => {
        const endpoint = path;
        fetchMovies(endpoint)
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    }, [])


    const fetchMovies = (endpoint) => {

        fetch(endpoint)
            .then(result => result.json())
            .then(result => {
                // console.log(result)
                // console.log('Movies',...Movies)
                // console.log('result',...result.results)
                setMovies([...Movies, ...result.results])
                setMainMovieImage(MainMovieImage || result.results[0])
                setCurrentPage(result.page)
            }, setLoading(false))
            .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error)
            )
    }

    const loadMoreItems = () => {
        let endpoint = '';
        setLoading(true)
        console.log('CurrentPage', CurrentPage)
        endpoint = loadpath;
        fetchMovies(endpoint);
    }

    const handleScroll = () => {
        const windowHeight = "innerHeight" in window ? window.innerHeight : document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
        const body = document.body;
        const html = document.documentElement;
        const docHeight = Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight);
        const windowBottom = windowHeight + window.pageYOffset;
        if (windowBottom >= docHeight - 1) {

            // loadMoreItems()
            console.log('clicked')
            buttonRef.current.click();
        }
    }



    return (

        <div>
            <div className="menu__container menu_search">
                <SearchMenu mode="horizontal" onChange={value => setSearchTerm(value)} />
            </div>

            <div style={{ width: '100%', margin: '0' }}>
                {MainMovieImage &&
                    <MainImage
                        image={`${IMAGE_BASE_URL}${IMAGE_SIZE}${MainMovieImage.backdrop_path}`}
                        title={MainMovieImage.original_title}
                        text={MainMovieImage.overview}
                    />

                }

                <div style={{ width: '85%', margin: '1rem auto' }}>

                    <Title level={2} > Latest movies </Title>
                    <hr />
                    <Row gutter={[16, 16]}>
                        {Movies && Movies.map((movie, index) => (
                            <React.Fragment key={index}>
                                <GridCard
                                    image={movie.poster_path ?
                                        `${IMAGE_BASE_URL}${POSTER_SIZE}${movie.poster_path}`
                                        : null}
                                    movieId={movie.id}
                                    movieName={movie.original_title}
                                />
                            </React.Fragment>
                        ))}
                    </Row>

                    {Loading &&
                        <div>Loading...</div>}

                    <br />
                    <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                        <button ref={buttonRef} className="loadMore" onClick={loadMoreItems}>Load More</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    )
}

export default LandingPage
```

**

> SearchMenu code:

**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { Menu } from 'antd';
import { Input } from 'antd';
//import LandingPage from '../../LandingPage/LandingPage';
import '../../NavBar/Sections/Navbar.css';

const SearchMenu = (props) => {
    console.log("props = " + props);
    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
    const { Search } = Input;
    const onSearch = value => console.log(value);

    function searchChangeHandler(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(e.target.value);
        setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
        props.onChange(e.target.value);
    }
    console.log("searchTerm = " + searchTerm);
    //console.log(props.onChange);

    return (
        <div className="searchMenu">
            <Menu mode={props.mode} />

            <Search
                placeholder="Search"
                allowClear onSearch={onSearch}
                style={{ width: 400 }}
                onChange={(e) => searchChangeHandler(e)}
            />
            

            {/*
            console.log("Search Term = " + searchTerm);
           <LandingPage search={searchTerm}/>
            */}
        </div>
    )
}

export default SearchMenu;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `searchTerm` state in `LandingPage` changes, but this doesn't trigger any updates to the API data. You defined an `onchange` function for the search term, but you haven't called it anywhere.

You can redo the search on every keystroke, or you can respond to clicks of a search button and [`onPressEnter`](https://ant.design/components/input/#Input) in your search input.  I'm going to redo the search on every change.  So we've already got `searchTerm` updating -- we just need to use it!

I think it makes sense to set `currentPage` *before* loading data rather than after, but that's just my opinion.  That way the effect can respond to changes in the page and the query.

Try this:

```
function LandingPage() {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
  const [mainMovieImage, setMainMovieImage] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);

  // do you need this?  could just call loadMoreItems() instead of click()
  const buttonRef = useRef(null);

  const loadMoreItems = () => {
    // just set the page, the effect will respond to it
    setCurrentPage((page) => page + 1);
  };

  const onChangeSearch = (value) => {
    // reset page to 1 when changing search
    setSearchTerm(value);
    setCurrentPage(1);
  };

  // run effect to load movies when the page or the searchTerm changes
  useEffect(() => {
    const endpoint =
      searchTerm === ""
        ? `${API_URL}movie/popular?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&page=${currentPage}`
        : `${API_URL}search/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&query=${encodeURIComponent(
            searchTerm
          )}&page=${currentPage}`;

    // could use async/await but promise/then is fine too
    setLoading(true);
    fetch(endpoint)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        // replace state on page 1 of a new search
        // otherwise append to exisiting
        setMovies((previous) =>
          currentPage === 1 ? json.results : [...previous, ...json.results]
        );
        // only replace if not already set
        // when should we reset this?
        setMainMovieImage((previous) => previous || json.results[0]);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error("Error:", error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }, [searchTerm, currentPage]);

  const handleScroll = () => {
    const windowHeight =
      "innerHeight" in window
        ? window.innerHeight
        : document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
    const body = document.body;
    const html = document.documentElement;
    const docHeight = Math.max(
      body.scrollHeight,
      body.offsetHeight,
      html.clientHeight,
      html.scrollHeight,
      html.offsetHeight
    );
    const windowBottom = windowHeight + window.pageYOffset;
    if (windowBottom >= docHeight - 1) {
      // loadMoreItems()
      console.log("clicked");
      buttonRef.current?.click();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    // cleanup function
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="menu__container menu_search">
        <SearchMenu
          mode="horizontal"
          value={searchTerm}
          onChange={onChangeSearch}
        />
      </div>

      <div style={{ width: "100%", margin: "0" }}>
        {mainMovieImage && (
          <MainImage
            image={`${IMAGE_BASE_URL}${IMAGE_SIZE}${mainMovieImage.backdrop_path}`}
            title={mainMovieImage.original_title}
            text={mainMovieImage.overview}
          />
        )}

        <div style={{ width: "85%", margin: "1rem auto" }}>
          <Title level={2}> Latest movies </Title>
          <hr />
          <Row gutter={[16, 16]}>
            {movies &&
              movies.map((movie, index) => (
                <React.Fragment key={index}>
                  <GridCard
                    image={
                      movie.poster_path
                        ? `${IMAGE_BASE_URL}${POSTER_SIZE}${movie.poster_path}`
                        : null
                    }
                    movieId={movie.id}
                    movieName={movie.original_title}
                  />
                </React.Fragment>
              ))}
          </Row>

          {loading && <div>Loading...</div>}

          <br />
          <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }}>
            <button
              ref={buttonRef}
              className="loadMore"
              onClick={loadMoreItems}
              disabled={loading} // disable button when fetching results
            >
              Load More
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I would make `SearchMenu` into a controlled component that both reads and updates the `searchTerm` state from `LandingPage` instead of having its own state.

```
const SearchMenu = ({ mode, value, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <div className="searchMenu">
      <Menu mode={mode} />

      <Search
        value={value}
        placeholder="Search"
        allowClear
        style={{ width: 400 }}
        onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for much improved and clean code, I learnt a lot from it as i'm beginner.I'm getting an error saying json.results is undefined:                                                                                 ```**TypeError: json.results is undefined**
/LandingPage.js
  44 | .then((json) => {
  45 |     // replace state on page 1 of a new search
  46 |     // otherwise append to exisiting
> 47 |     setMovies((previous) =>
     | ^  48 |         currentPage === 1 ? json.results : [...previous, ...json.results]
  49 |     );
  50 |     // only replace if not already set```

Comment: And also, When the searchTerm changes (in searchMenu) the previous loaded results in movies are not removed (the new searchTerm results are appending in the movie result rather than starting from index 0. I can't figure out that too :/ ). Can you please help me in that too. Thanks

Comment: Ok so that’s saying that the JSON that you received from the API doesn’t have a .results property.  I think your previous code was using the same property but maybe it’s wrong?  You can add a check “if (json.results) {“.  I recommend that you console.log the json variable to see what it looks like.  I am expecting it to have a .results property which contains an array of movies.  Does it?

Comment: I thought I handled the changing of the search term with setCurrentPage(1) in onChangeSearch and the currentPage === 1 ternary in the fetch so I’m not sure why that’s not working ‍♀️

Comment: Yes, the API have a .results property. I am sharing you the API link here (you can check it if it helps): https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=b4a549abb798b19dbb7e63335d135053&language=en-US&page=$1  . And the API is also working fine.  and after doing console.log(json), i am getting ```Object  {
  "errors": (1)[
    0: "page must be greater than 0"
    length: 1
  ]
}```. And also tried to put the check “if (json.results) {“, still same error

Comment: Ok I think I know what’s happening with that error at least.  It is saying that you are searching with page=0.  In my code I’m using page 1 as the first page.  In your code before you were starting with currentPage as 0 and adding 1 to it.  So I suspect that you’re still doing that.  My code is expecting that the initial value of currentPage is 1 instead of 0.

Comment: Thanks a lot again..it worked (I changed the currentPage state from 0 to 1). Your code is working exactly what you said and it's perfect for me. Thanks again. now only one thing is remaining, the MainMovieImage is not setting at results[0]. in your code it's 
```// only replace if not already set
   // when should we reset this?
      setMainMovieImage((previous) => previous || json.results[0]);
```

Comment: I think you can remove that state entirely!  Instead just use `const mainMovieImage = movies[0];` https://codesandbox.io/s/the-movie-db-search-pagination-162sn?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks Linda. I couldn't think it was this easy. Now it's working completely perfect. Thanks a lot again..

Comment: I played with your code a bit more so that we stop loading pages after the end has been reached.

Comment: wow! you made it in few minutes what i did in one week...it's much more than what i expected i would get from here..Thank you Linda..now I'll work on those movies from the list which has no poster available(I think I can do it, atleast i'll try first)

Comment: Doing things the first time is hard!  Doing them the hundredth time is easy.  So just keep on learning and practicing :)